# Get Exception while executing a oracle procedure in java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to execute a procedure in oracle, but i get a exception while executing the procedure.Please help me where i am wrong.

**Error :**

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 36:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset
The symbol ")" was substituted for ";" to continue.
```

**Procedure :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_101"."AVG_UNLOADING" 
(
P_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
P_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
P_VANID IN NUMBER,
P_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN P_CURSOR
FOR
select CARGO_NAME,IMP_EXP_NAME,'TEMP_CARGO_Import',ROUND(SUM(QTY)/((((extract(day from max(END_TIME)-DISCHRG_CMNCD_ANCHRG_TM)*(24*60))+
(extract(day from max(END_TIME)- DISCHRG_CMNCD_ANCHRG_TM)*(60)) + (EXTRACT(DAY FROM max(END_TIME)- DISCHRG_CMNCD_ANCHRG_TM)))-DELAYS)/(24*60))) QTY
from(SELECT (SELECT C.CARGO_CATEGORY_NAME FROM IPT_CARGOMASTER C WHERE C.CARGO_CODE =LL.CARGO_CODE )CARGO_NAME,IL.IMP_EXP_NAME,CASE L.CARGO_TYPE_CODE WHEN 'VC001' THEN LL.DISCHARGE_QUANTITY WHEN 'VC002' THEN LL.QUANTITY_GMT WHEN 'VC004' THEN LL.QUANTITY_GMT 
else LL.DISCHARGE_QUANTITY end QTY ,L.DISCHRG_CMNCD_ANCHRG_TM,LL.END_TIME ,(SELECT SUM(T3.TOTAL_TIME) FROM IPT_LOADUNLOADDELAYLINES T3 WHERE T3.ID = L.ID AND T3.MINUS_DELAY_HOURS = 'true') AS DELAYS    
,LL.LINE_ID,L.VAN_ID FROM IPT_LOADINGUNLOADING L JOIN IPT_LOADUNLOADOPERATIONLINES LL ON L.ID=LL.ID  LEFT JOIN IPT_IMPORTEXPORTFORM I ON I.VAN_ID=L.VAN_ID JOIN IPT_IGMEPCARGOLINES IL ON I.ID=IL.ID AND LL.CARGO_CODE=IL.CARGO_CODE  
where L.PORTDETAIL_CODE= P_CODE and I.PORTDETAIL_CODE=L.PORTDETAIL_CODE and IL.IMP_EXP_NAME like '%KKR%' AND LL.END_TIME<=TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(P_DATE || ' 06:59'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI')   
and L.VAN_ID in (P_VANID )
)t group by CARGO_NAME, IMP_EXP_NAME, 'TEMP_CARGO_Import',DISCHRG_CMNCD_ANCHRG_TM,DELAYS;
END AVG_UNLOADING;
```

**Executing procedure**

```
stkagentlist = "{call AVG_UNLOADING(?,?,?,?}";
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(stkagentlist);
callableStatement.setString(1, portCode);  
callableStatement.setString(2, dt );  
callableStatement.setString(3, vanids ); 
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Group by get executed before select and you specify (DELAYS) in the group by, I think this is the error

Comment: where is your java code which call the proc

Comment: Your query is an absolute mess. Neat layout is not some fashionable extra, it's a real help when it comes to debugging code.

Comment: `stkagentlist = "{call AVG_UNLOADING(?,?,?,?}";` Is this right? Your call is missing a matching right bracket.

Comment: `?}";` should be `?)}";`

Comment: Thanks , i missing right bracket .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stkagentlist = "{call AVG_UNLOADING(?,?,?,?}";
```

I think in this statement the closing round bracket is missing, it should be:

```
stkagentlist = "{call AVG_UNLOADING(?,?,?,?)}";
```